# Failed to restore file with extundelete

Tags: data-recovery, extundelete

I accidentally deleted the file `.vimrc` in my `$HOME` directory.

I rebooted the system and accessed it as `root`.

Then:

`$ sudo mount -o remount,ro /dev/sda5`

`$ sudo extundelete /dev/sda5 --restore-file /home/xralf/.vimrc`

The output of the command indicates that it failed to restore `.vimrc` file.

Is the file already absolutely lost or is there some other possibility to recover it?

Comment: From your regular backups?

Comment: @psimon I haven't back up it for 2 years. I forgot for this and how many configurations I have made in it :-(

Comment: shutdown and reboot are very busy times with regard to disk write. At least a lot more than idly sitting there.

Comment: In the future store stuff in revision control, and backup the repository. (I recommend git or mercurial).

Comment: @richard Good idea. I have to edit my `.vimrc` for my most used settings to work. I hope I haven't deleted something else important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most probably lost.  During the reboot, your system would have written to disk many times.

I know it's too late now, but the second you noticed you'd deleted the file you should have physically powered off the machine (not gracefully shut it down - pull the power cord).

At that point you could have booted with a recovery CD/USB ensuring that the disk where the file was located isn't mounted `rw`.

Next, you could have used your recovery tools to try and save the file.  There is no guarantee, but you'd have stood a better chance.

There are special boot disks available for this sort of task such as `System Rescue CD` and `The Ultimate Boot CD`.